# Positions from a binary file of an undetermined number of arrays

Tags: c, file, binaryfiles

I want to print the position of every array in a binary file. The structure of the array is: n, then n numbers (all long, n too).
This is the code:

```
int main() {
   FILE \*f = fopen("a.bin", "rb");
   while(!feof(f)) {
      printf("-(%d)\\n", ftell(f));
      long n; fread(&n, 1, sizeof(long), f);
      fseek(f, n \* sizeof(long), SEEK_CUR);
   }
}
```

My idea was to read until the end of the file, but it loops infinitely.

Comment: Two comments: `fread()` parameters shuffled, and verification of any/all return codes not performed. A black box that doesn't verify its own operation...